# If condition not working as expected c#

Tags: c#

This is now bugging me , i have tried to fix it for the past hour but still no luck!

I hope some one could spot what i'm doing wrong . here is my code:

```
var maxDays = 30;
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now; //todays date
 DateTime lastAction = '2017-03-07 12:47:58.967';
  double totalDays = (lastAction - today).TotalDays;
  var days = Math.Round(totalDays);
if(days > maxDays)
{
  //never hits this even though days is greater than max days ..i'm so confused 
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what did the debugger show you?

Comment: what debugger, it doesn't even compile

Comment: I give the benefit of the doubt and assume that the real code does compile and run

Comment: @pm100 `DateTime lastAction = '2017-03-07 12:47:58.967';` won't compile.

Comment: it compiles gents... lastAction is date from a database

Comment: Did you debug the code? Inspect the value of `days` to see if it matches what you expected? Why didn't you post compilable code in your question?

Comment: If you're looking for totalDays (elapsed since lastAction) shouldn't it be (today - lastAction). The way you have it, days will be a negative number which will not be greater than maxDays which is a positive number.

Comment: THere is no way this compiles. the assignment of lastaction is wrong in many ways. I assume that you are paraphrasing the actual code. Others think that you cannot distinguish between code that wont compile and code that runs but doesnt do what you expect

Comment: No, it *does not compile*. This is not valid C#: `DateTime lastAction = '2017-03-07 12:47:58.967';` Instead it should probably be `DateTime lastAction = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-07 12:47:58.967");` or some variant of ParseExact.

Comment: Try   DateTime lastAction = new DateTime(2017,03,07, 12,47,58,967);   It compiles

Comment: and I will then loop back to - what does the debugger show?

Comment: @1future - As denoted by several other people here, your provided code example does NOT compile as provided.  Please provide a [mcve] and the exact error you are receiving.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger please. This can be solved in 5 seconds with your own effort by mousing over the variables in the if.

Comment: @Kevin That's the only correct answer, imo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Duplicate problem as here:
[C# Number of days between two dates problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856545/c-sharp-number-of-days-between-two-dates-problem)

`Timespan.TotalDays` can be negative. So in your case it is almost guaranteed that lastAction - today will be a negative number, and so will always be less than 30.

If you only care about the absolute value of days, use `Math.Abs` otherwise re-arrange so that you are subtracting lastAction from today `(today - lastAction)`.
Note that due to rounding, your condition will still not be triggered if there is less than 1 day difference.

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible you are subtracting a larger value (today) from a small value (lastaction) which should result in a negative number making days negative?

That and you do need to do an explicit parse on the string to make it a date:

```
DateTime lastAction = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-07 12:47:58
     .967");
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things.

First you cant convert a string to DateTime like that. You should do something like this instead. `DateTime lastAction = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-07 12:47:58.967");`

Second, Just as @MikeS said, you are subtracting the lastAction from Today, which is resulting in a negative number (in this case its like -173). You should flip that statement. `double totalDays = ( today - lastAction).TotalDays;`

Your whole section should look something like this.

```
var maxDays = 30;
DateTime today = DateTime.Now; //todays date
DateTime lastAction = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-07 12:47:58.967");
double totalDays = ( today - lastAction).TotalDays;
var days = Math.Round(totalDays);
if (days > maxDays)
{
    // now this is hit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I did something stupid .. I had

```
double totalDays = (lastAction - today).TotalDays; // returns -176
```

changed my code to:

```
 double totalDays = (today - lastAction).TotalDays; //returns 176
```

Comment: IMHO - it would be better to accept one of the answers that had already pointed this out than to create a new answer...

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem:
You didn't parse the string to DateTime.

`DateTime lastAction = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-03-07 12:47:58.967");`

Your second problem:
You were receiving a negative value, and checking if it's bigger.

```
var days = (Math.Round(totalDays)) * (-1);
```

Like this, it should work.